# Bind wildcard entry capturing all undefined (NXDOMAIN) domains instead of just from the local zone, but only for curl,wget,chrome etc

Tags: nginx, http, bind, linux-networking

My setup redirects undefined hosts on the local network to a custom 404 page; so for `invalidhostname.subdomain.example.com` the **bind9** server would redirect to `nginxProxy.subdomain.example.com`. (that itself redirects to the 404 page hosted on another server)

*It works as expected for local undefined host names*.

But when it comes to `askljdaksjdad.com`, `nslookup`,`host`,`dig` all correctly return **NXDOMAIN**, but `google-chrome`, `curl` and `wget` all deliver the custom 404 page from my subdomain. And it's happening on multiple linux machines on the network.

The relevant parts of the configuration files are:
on bind server:`/etc/bind/zones/forward.subdomain.example.com`

```
subdomain.example.com       IN SOA  bind01.subdomain.example.com. nitin.subdomain.example.com (
                64         ; serial
                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                )
            NS  ns02.subdomain.example.com.
            NS  bind01.subdomain.example.com.
$ORIGIN subdomain.example.com.
;*                  CNAME   nginxProxy
*.subdomain.example.com.    CNAME   nginxProxy
nginxProxy          A   192.168.1.200
```

on nginxProxy:`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
server {
# Server:port pair that this instance of nginx is running on and should listen to for incoming connections(IP address or name)
# Add "default_server" before the end of the line if this is the default server/role
    listen       nginxProxy.subdomain.example.com:80;

# Set name of the virtual server
    server_name subdomain.example.com *.subdomain.example.com www.subdomain.example.*;

# Address of target/upstream VM/server that hosts the actual service.
    set $target http://web.subdomain.example.com:8080/404/error.html;

# Location configuration
    location / {
# resolver directive needed here if using variables with server names for proxy_pass directive; as nginx doesn't like calling the unix resolver after configuration.
    resolver 192.168.1.210;
    proxy_pass $target;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

So what am I missing here?? This is not the expected behaviour, right?